# Python OpenCV it's not recognizing my second WebCam [ CLOSED ]

Tags: python, opencv, webcam-capture

I'm trying to use a different WebCam from my notebook on opencv python with this code:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow(frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But when I try this error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\lucas\Desktop\VSCODE\brincando\webCam2.py",line 8, in <module>
   cv2.imshow("Camera",frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.hight>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

When I try to use 0 on cv2.VideoCapture it works and when I close it gives me this warning:

```
[ WARN:0] global C:\projcts\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

If I don't connect the second WebCam it works normally

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you didnt break from the while loop on "q".

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow(frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break # Add this

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

See [sentdex's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jvf5y21ZqtQ)

Comment: Actually I've discovered that the problem can be the WebCam Driver, but since it's a old camera I didn't found the right drivers, even in the original site for windows 10 so I can't do much. Thank you anyway. And I just forgot to put the break here in my code it's right